# HTML doesn't load after cache clear/hard reset but will successive times

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

So I'm working on a very simple web app. When I do a cache clear and hard reset, or I open the page in a different browser, it won't display everything. But then every refresh after that the display is fine. Is this something wrong with my code? Here's a copy of my HTML.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>Small Store</title>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
</head>

<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="store">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="box" id="Store">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Store</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td><em>Item</em></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><em>Price</em></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in store">
                    <td><b>{{item.Name}}</b></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>{{item.Price|currency}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-disabled="store.money<item.Price" ng-click="buy(item)">Buy</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="Stock" ng-hide="stock.length===0">
        <table>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">Stock</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><em>Item</em></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td><em>Quantity</em></td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="item in stock" ng-hide="item.Quantity<1">
                    <td><b>{{item.Name}}</b></td>
                    <td>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td>
                    <td>{{item.Quantity}}</td>
                    <td>
                        <button ng-click="sell(item)">Sell</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="box" id="Cart" ng-hide="cart.length===0">
    <!-- TO IMPLEMENT -->
    </div>
</div>
<div id="Editor">
    <!-- TO IMPLEMENT -->
</div>
<div id="money">
    Remaining money: {{money|currency}}
    <p>
        <input type="checkbox" name="Edit" value="true"> Edit store
        <br>
    </p>
</div>
<script src="app.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

And [here it is in codepen](http://codepen.io/WorkForPizza/pen/Pwrejd) with the css and javascript. The error persists in codepen so I think the error is in my code but I'm not exactly sure..

Comment: Is this a typo? `<button ng-disabled="store.money<item.Price" ng-click="buy(item)">Buy</button>`. Also, your codepen is working fine for me.

Comment: Code pen working fine, opened in three browsers IE11, FF 37.0.1 and Chrome 41.0.2272.118m and they all looked the same first time and the same again after refreshes ...

Comment: @Huey yes! it was a typo. Thank you.